# How to use bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) in array

Tags: theme-development, themes, array, bloginfo

I want to pass `bloginfo( 'template_directory' )` in an array

I tried this but not working.  How to write it correctly?

```
<?php
get_the_image( array( 'size' => 'full',
              'default_image' => bloginfo( "template_directory" ) .'/img/dflt.png',
              'image_scan' => true,
              'link_to_post' => false ) );
?>
```

`get_the_image` is a function from Justin Tadlock plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bloginfo()` is using `echo`, you need a function that returns its value: `get_bloginfo()`.

In this case you could also use just the function `get_bloginfo()` is using: `get_template_directory_uri()`.